# I am trying to sort a list in python with integers and a float using "a.sort([1])" and it is not working

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list in python with integers and a float using 
"a.sort([1])" (I am sorting it from the second element of the list) but it keeps on saying "TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function". What should I do? Also my list looks like this: 
["bob","2","6","8","5.3333333333333"]

Comment: Read docoumentation on `list.sort`  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 2):

[Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32296030/21945) does a nice job of explaining how to use `sort` correctly.

I want to point out, however, that sorting strings of numbers is not the same as sorting numeric values (ints and floats etc.). Sorting by strings will use character collating sequence to determine the order, e.g.

```
>>> l = ['100','1','2','99']
>>> sorted(l)
['1', '100', '2', '99']
```

but this is probably not what you want; 100 is greater than 2 and so should appear further back in the list than 2. You can sort by numeric value, but retain strings for the list items using the `key` parameter to `sort()`:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: float(x))
['1', '2', '99', '100']
```

Here the `key` is a lambda function that converts its argument to a float. The `sort()` routine will use the converted value as the sort key, not the string value that is actually contained in the list.

To sort from the second list item on, do this:

```
>>> a = ["bob", "2", "6", "8", "5.3333333333333"]
>>> a[1:] = sorted(a[1:], key=lambda x: float(x))
>>> a
['bob', '2', '5.3333333333333', '6', '8']
```

Comment: Who's Paul? That link links back to this question.

Comment: @PM2Ring : try clicking the link. It links to another answer for this question. The owner ([Paul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/103081/paul)) seems to have deleted his answer so maybe that's why you're asking?

Comment: Ah! That explains it. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to do "a.sort()". it will sort your list.
sort cant get 1 as argument.
read more here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_sort.htm

if you trying to sort every element except the first one try to do:

```
a[1:] = sorted(a[1:])
```